# Using Multiple xpaths in Scrapy Selector

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have to crawl data with Scrapy like this:

```
<div class="data"
     data-name="{"id":"566565", "name":"data1"}" 
     data-property="{"length":"444", "height":"678"}"
>
    data1
</div>
<div class="data"
     data-name="{"id":"566566", "name":"data2"}" 
     data-property="{"length":"555", "height":"777"}"
>
    data2
</div>
```

I need `data-name` and `data-property` attributes. My selector is:

```
selections = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="data"]/attribute::data-property').extract()
```

How can I include `data-name` attribute in selections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath should return `data-property` and `data-name` attributes :

```
//div[@class='data']/attribute::*[name()='data-property' or name()='data-name']
```

XPath Demo : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/e720602b62461f3600989be73eb15aec

---

If you need to return the two attributes as a pair in a certain format for each parent `div`, then this can't be done using pure XPath 1.0. Some python would be required, maybe using list comprehension (not tested) :

```
selections = [div.xpath('concat(@data-property, " ", @data-name)').extract() \
                   for div in Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="data"]')]
```

Comment: 'data-name' hasn't included.

Comment: I have to merge 2 selection in one (selections)

Comment: @TheNone that can't be done using pure XPath 1. See updated answer. The example will return concatenation of the two attributes for each `div`